# Use old wordpress data

Tags: php, wordpress

So recently I had a virus on my site and I've copied my WordPress `content` folder to my local computer and did a backup of the database and whole site (using cPanel). Then I deleted everything from `public_html` and installed fresh WordPress. After clearing `content` folder from a virus I put it back and overwrite freshly installed wp. I connected WordPress to the old database. I set up a theme that I used and that is it. And after all this, my site is still blank. Also inside `content` folder on hosting, I have images under `content/uploads` folder but when I go in `media` on admin panel, nothing is there. What is the problem?

Here are some images:
[image]
[image]

Also i uploaded one image and it set it tho the folder `content/2017/6/image` where i already have 10 images but in media library is only the latest one added

I found out the problem. Inside my database i have prefix `WPN7_TableName` and at setup i set it to `wp_TableName`. How can i change this?

Comment: What about the database: did you dropped everything and restored from a backup or it is as it is?

Comment: It is as it is. I explained. Copy content folder to local computer (made all backups just in case), fresh install wordpress, put back content. Connected wordpress to old database and set up theme but for some reason it is loading old pages and images even if it is saving new one to the folder where i already have images `wp-content`

Comment: @RakibulIslam could you look at my question again, i found out the problem so if you could help me with that

Comment: I couldn't understand where you used `wp_TableName`. Can you be more clear. And if you can share some screenshot of your database that would be helpful.

Comment: I found out. I didn't know how it is called but found out it is `Table Prefix` and i changed it from `wp-config.php` from `wp_` to `wpn7_`.

Comment: Why don't you change the `$table_prefix` to the appropriate one in `wp-config.php` as you have found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced `%table_prefix` inside `wp-config.php` from `wp_` to `wpn7_` just like old one was.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try these and let me know if that helps.

**N.B.: Remember you must completely backup both database and files on your server before proceeding further.**

In your `wp-config.php` file add the below line at the very bottom:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Now visit this page:

http://***www.yoursite.com***/wp-admin/maint/repair.php [Replace *www.yoursite.com* with your actual one]

And there you will see the option to repair the database. Go with that and check if that solves the problem.